# Avoid c++ vector copy

Tags: c++, vector, struct, copy, shared-ptr

I want to avoid making copies of a vector that is quite large. Here is a pretty clear example of what the issue is:

```
struct MyStruct {
    std::vector<int> v;
    int x;
}

class MyClass {
    MyStruct lastStruct_;
public:
    MyStruct create_struct() {
        MyStruct s = { std::vector<int>(1000000, 1), 1234 };
        lastStruct_ = s;  // THIS IS A FULL COPY, PROBLEM
        return s; // THIS SHOULD NOT BE A COPY AS PER C++11 AND UP
    }
    MyStruct getLastStruct() {
            return lastStruct_;
    }
}

void main()
{
    MyClass c;
  for (int i = 0; i < A_LOT; i++)
  {
    writeToDisk(c.create_struct());
  }
  //MEANWHILE IN OTHER THREAD:
  // while(true)
  //   updateUI(c.getLastStruct());
}
```

How can I avoid making copies here ? I am trying to solve this with shared pointers but I am still new to these. Would something like this work (syntax might be off)?

```
struct MyStruct {
    std::vector<int> v;
    int x;
}

class MyClass {
    std::shared_ptr<MyStruct> lastStruct_;
public:
    MyStruct create_struct() {
        auto s = std::maked_shared<MyStruct>({ std::vector<int>(1000000, 1), 1234 });
        lastStruct_ = s;
        return *s; 
    }
    std::shared_prt<MyStruct> getLastStruct() {
            return lastStruct_;
    }
}

void main()
{
    MyClass c;
  for (int i = 0; i < A_LOT; i++)
  {
    writeToDisk(c.create_struct());
  }
  //MEANWHILE IN OTHER THREAD:
  // while(true)
  //   updateUI(c.getLastStruct()->data());
}
```

Comment: I would just like to point out that writing to disk will be a larger performance bottleneck than copying a vector by far.  Are you sure you're optimizing the appropriate part of your program?  Did this show up as an issue when you ran performance profiling on your code?

Comment: Is there a reason you are storing in lastStruct_ ?  If so, did you mean to return that on create_struct instead of the created s?

Comment: Sadly yes, the data has to be written to disk, that is why it is done on a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the most obvious way:

```
struct MyStruct {
    std::vector<int> v;
    int x;
}

class MyClass {
    std::shared_ptr<MyStruct> lastStruct_;
public:
    std::shared_ptr<const MyStruct> create_struct() {
        auto s = std::maked_shared<MyStruct>({ std::vector<int>(1000000, 1), 1234 });
        // acquire lock
        lastStruct_ = s;
        // release lock
        return s; 
    }
    std::shared_ptr<const MyStruct> getLastStruct() {
        // acquire lock
        auto j = lastStruct_;
        // release lock
        return j;
    }
}

void main()
{
  MyClass c;
  for (int i = 0; i < A_LOT; i++)
  {
    auto j = c.create_struct();
    writeToDisk(*j);
  }
  //MEANWHILE IN OTHER THREAD:
  // while(true)
  // {
  //   auto j = c.getLastStruct();
  //   updateUI(j->data());
  // }
}
```

Notice that we replace the object by replacing a shared pointer to the old object with a shared pointer to the new object. The code that's accessing the old object keeps it alive until it's done with it.

You need some kind of lock to protect `lastStruct_` from being modified in one thread while it's accessed in another thread.

Comment: Ok so I was pretty close. Indeed some additions will be required to make this thread safe. Could you go into more details as to why you do not simply return lastStruct_ in the get method ?

Comment: @XDD Because `lastStruct_` may get modified in another thread. What could a thread possibly do with a reference to an object that might get modified by another thread? We need to give the thread its own shared pointer to an object that cannot be changed so that it can use it safely.

Comment: That makes sense. To make sure I am getting this straight: if lastStruct_ is modified, it will be because a new pointer to an other address was created and copied in it. Meawhile, the newly created `j` will still be pointing to the old lastStruct_ address that contains the untouched data. When j becomes out of scope, no shared pointer will be left pointing to that address, so C++ will finally delete it. Is this correct ? Thank you for the detailed explanations

Comment: @XDD You got it.